# How can I know why my iphone app crashes and what is taking too much resources to make it crash?

Tags: iphone

Program received signal:  “0”.
warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame

What is this error?
Is there a testing device for the iphone app to know which program element is taking the resources to make the app crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the Object Allocations tool in instruments. This gives you a quick overview over what type of Objects you are allocating and also provides you with a history of what methods are responsible for the creation of those objects. It also shows you if those objects get deallocated again, by looking at the difference between living and transatory objects you might be able to spot some leaks.

Another method would be to check the Activity Monitor and to have a look at the development of the memory over time and what features of your app have the largest impact on it.

You can run these tools from Xcode using Run -> Run with performance tool

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 3.2.1 there is a new option to Build and Analyze which helps figure out memory leaks etc so you should try running that after each large code change.

Other than that you should make it good practice to release everything that needs releasing as you add it to avoid a long process afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can always debugg the code using linebreaks.........

to test the app
use  Instruments.......